# Using configmap make container keep creating directories

Tags: kubernetes

I am using configmaps to populate configuration of few services. One container though is having a weird behavior. Several directories are created upon instanciation and then new ones every 2 minutes:

```
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:45 ..2982_15_02_14_45_49.335148891
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:45 ..2982_15_02_14_45_52.091968736
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:45 ..2982_15_02_14_45_53.797898431
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:45 ..2982_15_02_14_45_54.421758226
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:45 ..2982_15_02_14_45_56.209637705
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:46 ..2982_15_02_14_46_00.970889748
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 14:46 ..2982_15_02_14_46_08.301261923
```

[..]

```
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:22 ..2982_15_02_15_22_01.877596759
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:24 ..2982_15_02_15_24_01.626300874
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:26 ..2982_15_02_15_26_01.042779297
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:28 ..2982_15_02_15_28_01.708510604
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:30 ..2982_15_02_15_30_01.032055163
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:32 ..2982_15_02_15_32_01.089879198
 0 drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            90 Feb 15 15:34 ..2982_15_02_15_34_02.798668133
 0 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            31 Feb 15 15:34 ..data -> ..2982_15_02_15_34_02.798668133
 4 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb 15 14:45 apps.d
 4 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Feb 15 14:45 conf.d
 0 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            21 Feb 15 14:45 fastcgi-params -> ..data/fastcgi-params
 0 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            20 Feb 15 14:45 frontend.conf -> ..data/frontend.conf
 0 lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            17 Feb 15 14:45 nginx.conf -> ..data/nginx.conf
 0 drwxrwxrwt    3 root     root           120 Feb 15 14:45 ssl
```

YAML looks like this:

```
volumeMounts:
[..]  
- name: default-nginx-config
  mountPath: /etc/nginx
- name: default-nginx-slash-srv
  mountPath: /srv

volumes:
[..]
- name: default-nginx-config
  configMap:
    name: web-frontend-default
    items:
    - key: fastcgi-params
      path: fastcgi-params
    - key: frontend.conf
      path: frontend.conf
    - key: nginx.conf
      path: nginx.conf
    - key: internal.conf
      path: conf.d/internal.conf
    - key: common-static-app.conf
      path: conf.d/common-static-app.conf
    - key: common-backends.conf
      path: conf.d/common-backends.conf
    - key: common-dynamic-app.conf
      path: conf.d/common-dynamic-app.conf
    - key: 00-generic.conf
      path: apps.d/00-generic.conf
    - key: default.conf
      path: apps.d/default.conf
- name: default-nginx-slash-srv
  configMap:
    name: web-frontend-default
    items:
    - key: probe.html
      path: probe.html
```

Any hint will be, of course, much appreciated :-)

Thank you

Comment: Suggestion: check kubelet error logs, in /var/log/kubelet.log for error messages from "atomic_writer.go".

Comment: Logical but smart advise :-)

I do see many "Volume is already mounted to pod, but remount was requested." but those seems legit.

However the nginx conf fails to be remounted because another volume containing ssl certs exists at the same level.

remove [..]/default-nginx-config/ssl: device or resource busy
configmap.go:182] Error writing payload to dir: remove [..]
[..] (durationBeforeRetry 2m0s). Error: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume [..]

Will follow-up but I guess moving the ssl directory out of the nginx conf dir will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well fixed :-)
Problem was two volumes mounted in the same target directory. k8s doesn't seem to like it.

Thank you Eric!

Answer (score 0):

I was also having issues with two files being accessed before they were fully mounted. The workaround was making my ENTRYPOINT a bash script that simply moved them from the mount directory in the root level, to the actual file location they were being used, then calling the program binary.